# Is there a LaTeX editor for Windows with an equivalent to RefTeX ?

Tags: bibtex, windows, reftex

I am currently using TexMaker on Windows to write my LaTeX documents. However, I would be very interested in a feature like RefTex (emacs module for bibtex) that would allow me to search directly in my bibtex files.
TexMaker just do auto-complete on the keys of the bibtex what is far less convenient.

Do you have an idea to help me ?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use emacs on windows? It works there.

If you are interested in working with bibtex files, there is also [jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) which is a nice bibliography manager. It is fully cross-platform.

Comment: Ok maybe have I no choice. I found TexMaker quite convenient (and btw I already had an operating system) but I will try emacs on windows anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`LaTeXTools` is a very elaborate extension for [Sublime Text](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) and [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/latextools), which also includes fuzzy search on complete `BibTeX` entries.